# How can I fetch each part from An Erlang Pid?

Tags: erlang, pid

`pid(A, B, C)` can generate a pid `<A.B.C>`, how can I get A, B and C from a pid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `pid_to_list`, [Erlang doc](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_pid-1), but you probably shouldn't since it is generally a bad practice.

Comment: Thank you, I just want to try Erlang a little.

Comment: It's not really defined what the separate parts actually mean. Though if the first is `0` then it's on a the same node, otherwise another node.